# Remodel a array after finding the cosine similarity

Tags: python, pandas, trigonometry

I have a data frame containing job occupation as main variable , for each occupation that is a bunch of skills that compose a job. Im trying to find the cosine similarity between jobs using cosine as a distance metric. So far I manage to get to the cosine matrix/array , however I cant get this array back to as a data frame containing the similarities between the occupation. Please see below a sample of the dataset, the code I been using so far and the expected result I am aiming to get.

**Data set**

```
INDEX           3D studio      Accountancy       Cooking      

3d modeling         1               0               0
IC auditor          0               1               0
Chef                0               1               0
```

### Apply cosine similariry

```
 import numpy as np
 from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
 from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

  dist_out = 1-pairwise_distances(data_k_T, metric="cosine")
```

The result is in form of a array

```
 0    1       2       3 
 1    1       0       0
 2    0       1       0.65
 3    0       0.65    1
```

How to I bring this to a pairwise comparison format, I've tried to use concat and reshape but I failed.

### The ideal result would be:

```
Occ_s          Occ_T            Score
3d modeling    3d modeling        1
3d modeling    IC auditor         0 
3d modeling    Chef               0.65
```

Note - The matrix is very large and this cosine score is fictitious.

Comment: Could you just reconfirm for your example that the score for the Chef in 3d modeling is 0.65? From the resulting array I would guess that it is 0, in which case you would only need to read the rows/columns to get the desired result.

Comment: @ Eulenfuchswiesel , hi and tks for a quick reply ... The score are fictitious , that are 2950 different possible skill types. I got a array float64 as a result of the cosine , I want to bring back to the real variable names as a pair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need `DataFrame` constructor with specify columns and index and then reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
dist_out = 1-pairwise_distances(data_k_T, metric="cosine")
print (dist_out)
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1.]]

df = pd.DataFrame(dist_out, index=data_k_T.index, columns=data_k_T.columns)
print (df)
             3Dstudio  Accountancy  Cooking
3d modeling       1.0          0.0      0.0
IC auditor        0.0          1.0      1.0
Chef              0.0          1.0      1.0

out = df.stack(0).reset_index()
out.columns = ['Occ_s','Occ_T','Score']
print (out)
         Occ_s        Occ_T  Score
0  3d modeling     3Dstudio    1.0
1  3d modeling  Accountancy    0.0
2  3d modeling      Cooking    0.0
3   IC auditor     3Dstudio    0.0
4   IC auditor  Accountancy    1.0
5   IC auditor      Cooking    1.0
6         Chef     3Dstudio    0.0
7         Chef  Accountancy    1.0
8         Chef      Cooking    1.0
```

Numpy solution:

```
a = np.repeat(data_k_T.index, len(data_k_T.columns))
b = np.tile(data_k_T.columns, len(data_k_T))
c = dist_out.ravel()

out = pd.DataFrame({'Occ_s':a, 'Occ_T':b, 'Score':c})
print (out)
         Occ_s        Occ_T  Score
0  3d modeling     3Dstudio    1.0
1  3d modeling  Accountancy    0.0
2  3d modeling      Cooking    0.0
3   IC auditor     3Dstudio    0.0
4   IC auditor  Accountancy    1.0
5   IC auditor      Cooking    1.0
6         Chef     3Dstudio    0.0
7         Chef  Accountancy    1.0
8         Chef      Cooking    1.0
```

Comment: , tks a lot... I had to do minor alterations due to the nature of my data.